# Irreducible Quadratic Polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$ when $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

It is well known that the polynomial $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ if and only if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. I was wondering if there is another universal degree $2$ polynomial that is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: No, there is no such polynomial.

Comment: Here's a sketch as to why no such polynomial exists: such a polynomial would correspond to a quadratic extension where the split primes are $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ upto finitely many extensions. In particular, the discriminant would have to be $4$ (by class field theory if you like) and we can enumerate all such quadratic extensions and check.

Answer (score 2):

For $p\ne 2$ the factorization of $X^2+bX+c\bmod p$ is given by $(\frac{b^2-4c}{p})$,  quadratic reciprocity says $(\frac{b^2-4c}{p})= f(p)$ with $f$ completely multiplicative and periodic of least period $\Delta$, in your assumption there is that $f(5)=f(13)=-1$ which implies that $f(65)=1$ and $\gcd(65,\Delta)=1$, thus $f(p)=1$ whenever $p\equiv 65 \bmod \Delta$, with Dirichlet theorem on arithmetic progressions take a prime $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4,p\equiv 65 \bmod \Delta$ to get $f(p)=1$.